# Strip excess outer text from all strings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have value array like this:

```
^ array:2 [▼
    0 => "random value1<tr>random string1</tr>random endvalue1"
    1 => "random value2<tr>random string2</tr>random endvalue2"
  )
]
```

How do I change the value of the dimensional array above to be like below:

```
^ array:2 [▼
    0 => "random string1"
    1 => "random string2"
  )
]
```

I'm trying using:

```
$array = array_map(function($key) {
    $exp = explode('<tr>', $tes);
    //$exp1 = explode('</tr>', exp[1]); -from this line3 my explode cant access array 
    return exp;

}, $myarray);
dd($array);
```

My array in line3 become like this:

```
^ array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
        0 => "random value1"
    1 => "random string1</tr>random endvalue1"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
        0 => "random value2"
    1 => "random string2</tr>random endvalue2"
    ]
  )
]
```

How to improve conditions like this, or have another way that is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [
    "random value1<tr>random string1</tr>random endvalue1",
    "random value2<tr>random string2</tr>random endvalue2",
];

$trim = collect($data)
    ->map(function (string $value) {
        preg_match('/(?<=<tr>)(.*)(?=<\/tr>)/', $value, $match);

        return empty($match) ? $value : $match[1];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Could be done this way, using the framework collect method to map through the values & extract the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because `preg_replace()` can be called once to make replacements on all elements, you can cast your collection `toArray()` and call `preg_replace()` on that. ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/S4))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace(
        '#.*<tr>(.*?)</tr>.*#',
        '$1',
        collect($data)->toArray()
    )
);
```

If you prefer to use `->map()` for chaining, you can make *n* number of `preg_replace()` calls. ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/o4))

```
var_export(
    collect($data)->map(fn($v) => preg_replace('#.*<tr>(.*?)</tr>.*#', '$1', $v))
);
```

If your data is already an array and you don't need to implement any collection methods, then just call `preg_replace()` on it. ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/94))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('#.*<tr>(.*?)</tr>.*#', '$1', $data)
);
```